# Material Design icon size in node-red

Tags: material-design, font-awesome, node-red

How can we change the icon size with the Material Design icon in a node-red dashboard button?
With the Font Awesome icons it's very easy to do. e.g. fa-car fa-4x.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be possible in node-red-dashboard (as of June 2018).

Since Font Awesome changes icon sizes by adding an extra class adjacent to the icon, i.e. `<i class="fa fa-car fa-4x"></i>`, you can add the size class in your node's icon field and it'll get inserted into the UI alongside the icon name.

However, Material Design alters icon sizes by adding classes to the *parent* element of the icon, i.e. `<i class="material-icons md-24">face</i>`, or by embedding sizes in the icon's SVG container. The only value you can provide in the node-red-dashboard "icon" field is the name of the icon, so there's no way to access the HTML elements needed to modify the size.

Here's what a Material Design "home" icon looks like when rendered in node-red-dashboard:

```
<ng-md-icon ng-if="iconType==='angular-material'" icon="home" class="ng-scope">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
    <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z"></path>
  </svg>
</ng-md-icon>
```

You may be able to add some custom CSS to target the SVG elements and alter the viewBox, width, and height, but you could at best change all icon sizes globally (or perhaps all of a specific type of icon), and wouldn't have control over individual icons.

Comment: thank you very much for your example and response. I was aware of the Awesome icon size adjustments. However to me, it is not yet to clear how I can implement your example in Node-Red. I will definitely try your example. Thanks again for your effort and time!